# Joda DateTime Timezone doesn't show up correctly

Tags: android, datetime, timezone, kotlin, jodatime

I'm using Joda-Time `DateTime` in Android.

It seems that the `DateTimeZone` doesn't work correctly. Maybe it has something to do with daylight savings?

At this moment, we have **GMT +2**. This will change in a few weeks, for the winter. Then it will be **GMT +1**. But right now it's not correct.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime

// GMT: Thursday 26 October 2017 12:11:54
val epochTime: Long = 1509019914 

var dateServer = LocalDateTime(epochTime * 1000).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Amsterdam"))
```

Expected (correct time in Amsterdam):

> 14:11:54 GMT+02:00 DST

Actual:

> 13:11  2017-10-26T13:11:54.000+01:00

Comment: What's the value of `DateTimeZone.getDefault()`?

Answer (score 4):

The `LocalDateTime` constructor gets the `epochTime` value and [converts to the default timezone](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html#LocalDateTime-long-) to get the date and time values - check the value of `DateTimeZone.getDefault()`, it's probably a timezone that's currently using the `+01:00` offset.

Then the `toDateTime` method creates a `DateTime` that corresponds to the same date and time represented by the `LocalDateTime`, but at the specified timezone (it just "attaches" the timezone to the date/time values, and no conversion is made).

If you want to get the date and time that corresponds to the `epochTime` in a specific timezone, just [create the `DateTime` directly](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime-long-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-):

```
val dateServer = DateTime(epochTime * 1000, DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Amsterdam"));
```

With this, `dateServer` will be:

> 2017-10-26T14:11:54.000+02:00

---

An example in my default timezone, just to be more clear. My default timezone (returned by `DateTimeZone.getDefault()`) is `America/Sao_Paulo`, which is using the offset `-02:00` (2 hours behind UTC) at October 26<sup>th</sup> 2017.

The `epochTime` 1509019914 corresponds to UTC `2017-10-26T12:11:54Z`.

When I do `LocalDateTime(epochTime * 1000)`, it gets the corresponding UTC value (12:11) and converts to the default timezone: in my case, to 10:11, so the `LocalDateTime` will have the value `2017-10-26T10:11:54`.

Then the `toDateTime` method just creates a `DateTime` that corresponds to the same date and time (`2017-10-26T10:11:54`), at the specified timezone. So it creates `2017-10-26T10:11:54` at Amsterdam (`+02:00`).

Your default timezone is probably one that uses the `+01:00` offset, which would explain the difference you're getting (12:11 UTC is first converted to `LocalDateTime` with 13:11, and then `toDateTime` creates 13:11 at Amsterdam).

---

## JSR310 - new date/time API

Joda-Time is in maintainance mode and is being replaced by the new APIs, so I don't recommend start a new project with it. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**.

*If you can't (or don't want to) migrate from Joda-Time to the new API, you can ignore this section.*

In Android, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for [Java 8's new date/time classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime). To make it work, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755)).

To get the corresponding UTC instant from the `epochTime`, you can use the `org.threeten.bp.Instant` class. Then you use a `org.threeten.bp.ZoneId` to convert it to a timezone, resulting in a `org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime`:

```
val dateServer = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochTime).atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"));
```

`dateServer` will be a `org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime`, with the value corresponding to `2017-10-26T14:11:54+02:00[Europe/Amsterdam]`.